# PInvoke marshalling of integers returning incorrect result

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, marshalling, unmanaged

I have a very simple function in an unmanaged DLL, but I'm not getting the correct return value back from it.

I can confirm that the general PInvoke mechanism is working with one function in my C DLL:

```
/* Return an integer */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long get_num()
{
    return 42;
}
```

I call the above unmanaged entry point like so from C# .NET:

```
[DllImport("My_C_DLL.dll")]
extern static long get_num();
// ...
long ans = get_num();
Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}.", ans);
```

This works fine, but passing marshalled parameters to another function in the DLL returns a wrong result:

```
/* Add two integers */
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) long add_num(long a, long b)
{
    long sum = a + b;

    return sum;
}
```

Called from C# as:

```
[DllImport("My_C_DLL.dll")]
extern static long add_num(long a, long b);

long a = 6, b = 12;
long sum = add_num(a, b);
Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}.", sum);
```

This gives me back a result of "6", or whatever I set the input value of **a** to be.

I'm guessing that some incorrect marshalling of the input values is messing up the call stack, resulting in the bad return value, but where is the error?

Comment: What is sizeof(long) in your C dll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems here. First of all C# `long` does not match C `long`. On Windows, `C` long is 32 bits. Use `int` in your C# code to match up with your C `long`.

The other problem is that the calling conventions probably don't match. You most likely have `cdecl` in your C DLL but the C# default is `stdcall`. Fix this by changing your p/invoke.

```
[DllImport("My_C_DLL.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
```

Comment: That did it.  All respondents mentioned the long size mismatch, but your inclusion of the calling convention mismatch was also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You might have a problem with the managed part defining **long** as a 64-bit integer, while your C compiler defining it as 32-bit integer.

You can either change **long** to **int** in your C# code, change **long** to **int64_t** in your C code, or force the 32-bit marshalling using [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (force marshalling only if all other ideas fail)

Answer (score 1):

Are you building the unmanaged DLL as 32-bit or 64-bit? Remember that the "long" type in C# is the same as System.Int64. That could be the source of your marshalling problem. If your DLL is 32-bit try changing your C# code to:

```
[DllImport("MY_C_DLL.dll")]
extern static int add_num(int a, int b);
```